# ¿Como dar salto de pagina con la librería dompdf en php?

Tags: php

Estoy creando un pdf con la librería dompdf en php , pero al momento de llegar al limite de mi hoja se encima los contenidos.

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema y no eh podido resolverlo... auxilio :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solo inserta esto, en el lugar donde quieras crear la nueva pagina

```
 <div style="page-break-after:always;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

También puedes crear una clase en tu hoja de estilos y referirla cuando la necesites:

```
<head>
    ...
    <style>
        .saltopagina{page-break-after:always;}
    </style>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <div clas='saltopagina'>
    ...
</body>
```